# Can the UPDATE() function be used multiple times within a SQL Server trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to test which columns have been updated in a trigger. I know that one can use the `UPDATE()` function like

```
IF (UPDATE(Column1) OR UPDATE(Column2) OR UPDATE(Column3))
    Do something...
```

but I need to able to test each of the columns separately and haven't had any success with the following

```
DECLARE TriggerCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT 
        SOPNUMBE, SOPTYPE, CMPNTSEQ, LNITMSEQ, ITEMNMBR, 
        QUANTITY, UNITPRCE, PRSTADCD 
    FROM 
        inserted;

OPEN TriggerCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM TriggerCursor INTO @sSOPNumber, @nSOPType, @nComponentSeq, 
                                   @nLineItemSeq, @sItemNumber, @cyQuantity, 
                                   @cyUnitPrice, @sShipToAddress;

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(QUANTITY)
        BEGIN
            SET @sAction = 'Changed Quantity from ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR,(select QUANTITY from deleted))) + ' to ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR, @cyQuantity));
        END;

        IF UPDATE(UNITPRCE)
        BEGIN
            IF LEN(@sAction) = ''
                SET @sAction = 'Changed Unit Price from ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR,(select UNITPRCE from deleted))) + ' to ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR, @cyUnitPrice));
            ELSE
                SET @sAction = @sAction + 'and Unit Price from ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR,(select UNITPRCE from deleted))) + ' to ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR, @cyUnitPrice));
            END;

            IF UPDATE(PRSTADCD)
            BEGIN
                IF @sAction = ''
                    SET @sAction = 'Changed ShipTo Address from ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR,(select PRSTADCD from deleted))) + ' to ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR, @sShipToAddress));
                ELSE
                    SET @sAction = @sAction + 'and ShipTo Address from ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR,(select PRSTADCD from deleted))) + ' to ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR, @sShipToAddress));
            END;

        EXEC NC_IDS_Insert_SOP_Audit_Record
                    @sSOPNumber, @nSOPType, @nComponentSeq,
                    @nLineItemSeq, @sUserId, @sAction, @dDate, @dTime;

    END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM TriggerCursor INTO  @sSOPNumber, @nSOPType, @nComponentSeq, @nLineItemSeq, @sItemNumber, @cyQuantity, @cyUnitPrice, @sShipToAddress;
END;

CLOSE TriggerCursor;
DEALLOCATE TriggerCursor;
```

Each time only Column1 seems to be tested, the others are ignored even though all three columns have been updated when updating the row.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that the UPDATES occur within a cursor, so not sure if that's what is causing my problem?

Comment: you need to provide an mvce demonstrating your issue

Comment: One word of caution. The UPDATE function returns true if the column is part of the update statement. It does NOT evaluate if the new and old values are different.

Comment: Your trigger is totally broken. You have subqueries pulling data from deleted. You have the common mistake of assuming there will only ever be a single row in deleted. This is a mess at this point. If you want to capture data changes it should be relational, not text explanation in a single column. And again, UPDATE does not check for differing values so you could have things like "Changed Unit Price from 12.34 to 12.34".

Comment: I would prefer a solution not involving triggers.  Get the data that matches the where clause of your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. From [UPDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an INSERT or UPDATE attempt was made on a specified column of a table or view. **UPDATE() is used anywhere inside the body of a Transact-SQL INSERT or UPDATE trigger to test whether the trigger should execute certain actions.**

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i INT, a INT, b INT, c INT);
INSERT INTO t(i,a,b,c) VALUES(1, 2,3,4);
INSERT INTO t(i,a,b,c) VALUES(2, 20,30,40);

CREATE TABLE log(t VARCHAR(MAX));

CREATE TRIGGER trg_t ON t AFTER UPDATE   
AS
BEGIN
   IF UPDATE(a)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO log VALUES ('Changed a');
   END;

   IF UPDATE(b)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO log VALUES ('Changed b');
   END;
END;
```

**[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=85fc100ac5fa4e03b6465c0d6a64749e)**

You need to remember that in SQL Server trigger is fired at statement level.

Comment: Excellent example. To further my point from my comment on the main question. If you execute Update t set a = a, b = b you will have two entries in the log even though no values were changed. I know that @lad2025 knows this, commenting so others understand this.

Comment: @SeanLange I've updated with my trigger script as forgot to mention it the updates occur within a cursor

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a solution not involving triggers.

Off the top of my head...

```
SELECT PrimaryKeyColumn,SOPNUMBER, SOPTYPE, CMPNTSEQ, LNITMSEQ,  ITEMNMBR, QUANTITY, UNITPRCE, PRSTADCD 
INTO #mytemptable
FROM SomeTable
WHERE <matches the condition you want>

UPDATE SomeTable
SET SOPNUMBER=@newvalue, etc etc
WHERE <matches the condition you want>

INSERT INTO Audits (audit table columns)
SELECT T.SOPNUMBER,S.SOPNUMBER, etc, etc
FROM #mytemptable T
INNER JOIN SomeTable S
ON S.PrimaryKeyColumn=T.PrimaryKeyColumn
```

Also try and avoid using cursors where you can.  often set-based operaitons can be used instead.